# Obter dados dentro de stdClass com varias stdClass uma dentro da outra em PHP

Tags: php, stdclass

Tenho como resposta essa stdClass:

```
stdClass Object ( [Search_AdvancedResult] => stdClass Object ( [ErrorMessage] => [MaxResults] => 1 [NumObjects] => 1 [QueryID] => 242122 [TotalResults] => 1 [Objects] => stdClass Object ( [RMWSObject2] => stdClass Object ( [ObjectID] => 549012 [EntryDate] => 2016-02-22 16:33:47 [EntryUserName] => de0210598 [ImportDate] => 2016-02-22 16:38:07 [CaptureDate] => 2016-02-22 16:33:00 [CaptureLocation] => DIRECIONAL [ClassCode] => SP1 [ClassName] => ADM Obra - Pagamentos por SP [SourceCode] => DIRECIONAL [SourceName] => Obras [TypeCode] => 311C [TypeName] => 311C (Central de Notas) [StateCode] => [StateName] => [FileType] => PDF [FileSize] => 97066 [BatchId] => 427031 [Indices] => stdClass Object ( [RMWSObjectIndex] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => LB [IndexCode] => OBRA [IndexName] => Obra e Fase [IndexValue] => 311C ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => LB [IndexCode] => REG [IndexName] => Regional [IndexValue] => Minas Gerais - MG ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => TX [IndexCode] => CPFCNPJ [IndexName] => CPF/CNPJ [IndexValue] => 06981180000116 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => TX [IndexCode] => NNF [IndexName] => Nº (Nota Fiscal ou Processo) [IndexValue] => 5502 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => DT [IndexCode] => DATAEMISS [IndexName] => Data de Emissão [IndexValue] => 22/02/2016 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => NU [IndexCode] => VALOR [IndexName] => *Valor [IndexValue] => 58.51 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => LB [IndexCode] => PR [IndexName] => Possui Rateio? [IndexValue] => NÃO ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => LB [IndexCode] => TDP [IndexName] => Tipo do Pagamento [IndexValue] => Boleto Anexado (Paga apenas essa nota) ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => TX [IndexCode] => NBDB [IndexName] => Nº do Boleto/Dados Bancários [IndexValue] => ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => LB [IndexCode] => PP [IndexName] => Pagamento Parcelado? [IndexValue] => NÃO ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => DT [IndexCode] => DATVENC [IndexName] => Vencimento (1ª parcela) [IndexValue] => 29/02/2016 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => TX [IndexCode] => DV [IndexName] => Demais Vencimentos [IndexValue] => ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => TX [IndexCode] => CB [IndexName] => Código do Boleto [IndexValue] => ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => TX [IndexCode] => DESCRICAO [IndexName] => Descrição [IndexValue] => NOVO LANÇAMENTO CEMIG P.5502 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [IndexDataType] => LB [IndexCode] => DOCSP1 [IndexName] => DOC - SP [IndexValue] => Contas de Consumo ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Preciso pegar diversos dados como por exemplo o CNPJ que esta presente neste trecho:

```
[IndexCode] => CPFCNPJ [IndexName] => CPF/CNPJ [IndexValue] => 06981180000116
```

Tentei usar `foreach()` mas existem muitas classes uma dentro da outra e não consigo avançar.

Comment: Não me parece fazer sentido usar um laço de repetição para acessar apenas um atributo. Por que não acessa ele diretamente seguindo a cadeia de objetos?

Comment: Já tentou acessar o objeto ? `$dados->objeto`

Answer (score 2):

Suponhamos que recebi um retorno nesse formato de objeto, para acessar as informações desse objeto, não preciso transformar ele em um array, posso acessar ele diretamente, segue o exemplo abaixo.

Retorno stdClass

```
$dados = stdClass Object ( 
            [cliente] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [codigo] => 1 
                            [nome] => Pedro 
                            [documento] => 12345678900 
             ) 
          )
```

Para recuperar algum valor desse meu objeto basta acessar o atributo que eu pretendo recuperar o valor.

```
$dados->cliente->documento
```

---

Referência: [Objetos - PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.object.php)

Comment: Deu certo! Buscando de camada em camada... Mais simples que eu imaginava! Muito obrigado!

$result->Search_AdvancedResult->Objects->RMWSObject2->ObjectID;

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, poderia marcar como resolvido para alcançar mais pessoas?